# What's the fastest way to locate a list element within a list in python?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

The list is similar to this:

```
[["12", "stuA", "stuB"], ["51", "stuC", "stuD"], ..., ["3234", "moreStuff", "andMore"]]
```

Now I need to locate an item (get index) only by its first value (e.g. `"332"`). Is there any better way to do this, apart from iterating from the first one to compare with each value?

Code:

```
index = 0
for item in thelist:
    if item[0] == "332":
         print index

    index = index + 1
```

Comment: Is the list sorted by the first item? Do you need to do that more than once?

Comment: It is important to know if the list is sorted in someway because if so, you can improve the search with binary search to make it really quick.

Comment: @reindeer: yeah you can sort it, actually the first value of each item is date but they are not consecutive(missing lots of days), so basically I need to get that day's data.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**No.** Without iterating you cannot find it, unless the list is already sorted. You can improve your code like this, with [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) and list comprehension.

```
[index for index, item in enumerate(thelist) if item[0] == "332"]
```

This will give the indices of all the elements where the first element is `332`.

If you know that `332` occurs only once, you can do this

```
def getIndex():
    for index, item in enumerate(thelist):
       if item[0] == "332":
          return index
```

Comment: OP says that the first value is a unique ID, so the list comprehension is not really needed.

Comment: @Henrik Please check now :)

Comment: Yes, good to include the regular function. The fact that list comprehension is nice doesn't make good ol' fashioned functions evil :)

Answer (score 12):

No-one's mentioned this yet, so I will - if you need to find an item by its value quickly (and presumably more than just once), you should change the data structure you use to be one that supports the kind of access you need. Lists support fast access by index, but not by item value. If you stored the information in a dict keyed by the first element in the lists, you would be able to find rows *very* quickly by that first value:

```
# Make a dict from the list of lists:
itemLookup = {item[0]: item for item in theList}

itemLookup["51"] # -> ["51", "stuC", "stuD"]
```

So the brief answer is no (although there is a quick-ish way using bisection if the list is sorted), the longer answer is use a dictionary if you want fast lookup.

Comment: We're not iterating the list to find the element, but to convert the list into a dictionary. This is only worth doing if we're going to be searching for items multiple times. if you had to do the lookup 100 times, better to do 1 full iteration followed by 100 fast lookups than to do 100 half-iterations (on average).

Answer (score 2):

If you can definitely guarantee the key you want exists exactly once, this could also work.

```
import itertools
itertools.ifilter(lambda x: x[1][0] == "332", enumerate(theList)).next()[0]
```

and would work for getting more than one occurrence if you modify it to use the generator object instead of immediately calling `next` as I do here.

If it's feasible, though, I would suggest moving the data to a `dict` format (`OrderedDict` if position of occurrence matters) with these integers as the keys (since you can guarantee they are unique), or potentially to a pandas DataFrame with the integers as the index.

Answer (score 2):

If the key occurs exactly once,

```
zip(*thelist)[0].index("332")
```

Comment: Pretty sure you want `zip(*thelist)[0].index("332")`